# Enforcing a rigid reusable template structure for similar posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I want to take some posts of a similar type, split them into named building blocks, store those separately, and finally put them together in a consistent nature using templates while rendering.

For example, I want my technical posts to resemble the structure of how I normally ask questions on the StackExchange sites, for example:

- What is the problem?
- What was my research?
- The solution I found
- Sources and further reading

Normally I would write out a post into a single uniform body, and just split it with h1's. Problem is, if I later decided to

- replace h1's with h2's, or
- make each of those headers have a permalinkable #anchor, or
- make the research block collapsed by default because most Googlers want just the answer anyway, or
- [mark them up as structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage), or in any other way I am not yet aware of,

I would have to edit all posts – which would be a lot of ineffective, error prone manual work. Instead, I would prefer to simply edit one reusable template.

I am therefore looking for a way to separate content from the templates, while enforcing a rigid post structure. This resembles how [the interfaces are being used in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022055/what-is-a-class-interface): if a given class implements some interface, this is a guarantee that it will have all methods defined in that interface, otherwise the compiler throws an error and won't let the program continue. Or in my case, if a post implements the e.g. "Q&A" type, this should be a guarantee it has all of the above sections.

Here's what I found:

- [Custom fields](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) won't work because apparently they're plain text
- [Post formats](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/post-formats/) won't work either because they do not enforce any post structure and are merely an indicator for the theme on how to render the post

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent block patterns and locked block placeholder templates. Note that product/plugin/library recommendations are off topic here, you should edit that part out of your question so it isn't closed as off topic

Comment: I have edited the question to make it look less like a recommendation request

Comment: For something like this I'd consider a custom post type with different content regions.  A Q&A content type with custom meta data and taxonomy.  Then you'd have to also create a template for displaying each of the entries, another for displaying a list of entries and if you wanted them merged with regular post types you'd also then write a replacement template for your standard posts feed.